# Symfony FormType Class not found

Tags: php, symfony, runtime-error

I have written a custom form type `UserType` and would like to render it but keep encountering the error `Could not load type "App\Form\Type\UserType": class does not exist.`

UserType.php (located in src\Form\Type\UserType.php)

```
namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserType extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->add('name', TextType::class, null, ['required' => true])
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, null, ['required' => true])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Foo user'])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([(
        'data_class' => User::class,
        'attr' => [(
            'class' => 'form-horizontal'
        )]
        )]);
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return UserType::class;
    }
}
```

UserController.php (located in src\controller\UserController.php):

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use App\Form\Type\UserType;
#[Route('/addUserForm', name: 'add_user_form')]
    public function addUserFromForm(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
```

I have renamed my custom type to see if Symfony finds the file at all but have not been successful.

Comment: That was just for troubleshooting. The error occurs with both names (same error message)

Comment: Same answer as before (added for testing purposes, to see if different paths make a difference). No change in the error message.

Comment: I would suggest showing the code as it is when you get the error message and the exact error message when you get it, so all details match.

Comment: I have edited the code to include the paths and imports of the controller

Comment: *"located in src\Form\Type\UserType"* so is it `src\Form\Type\UserType\UserType.php`? If so then it needs to be `src\Form\Type\UserType.php` instead..

Comment: No, it is located in ´src\Form\Type\UserType.php´

Comment: Edited my comment as i see you say it is located in `src\Form\Type\UserType.php`

Comment: No, it is located in the Type folder

Comment: I think it is from your `public function getExtendedType()` method in the UserType, try omitting that method, you will need to return a static self but not sure why you would need that.

Comment: Why is this class an extension of AbstractTypeExtension and not of AbstractType? Looks like you are trying to create an extension for UserType, but you have not defined it.

Comment: As @IanMcL says is correct, i missed that.